# IDA Pro 7.0 showing incorrect LOCALS in pseudocode view

Tags: ida, hexrays, local-variables

Whenever I debug something and I switch to pseudocode and then rename some of the "variables" that IDA Pro creates, the values shown in the LOCALS window don't match what the actual values of those variables are.

Is there a way to fix that behaviour?

Comment: Provide an example with real codes and variables.